# How can I use Pentaho schema workbench on Oracle?

Tags: oracle, pentaho

My Pentaho Schema Workbench runs just fine with a local mySQL database server. However, when I try to connect it with the Oracle databases of my company, it freezes after satisfactorily establishing the connection.

Officially, version 3.2.2 solves the problem (http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PSW-97). But I have downloaded that version and the problem remains, even though I specify the database name.

What would you advise me to try?

Additional information: I'm positive that the Oracle servers are working propperly.

Answer (score 0):

It is not freezing, but it is getting the entire schema of your database, and in some oracle databases this is huge, and oracle is very slow in returning it.

There are various solutions on the Pentaho forums, one of which is here:

http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?88976-Schema-Workbench-very-slow-against-Oracle11G&highlight=all_objects

You can also filter the schemas too.

Answer (score 0):

As given in this "http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PSW-97:
FILTER_SCHEMA_LIST Parameter with value of your schema name should solve this.
It worked for me. I am using oracle 11G.